# Google Maps: embed with search point "deselected"

Tags: html, google-maps, google-maps-embed

Is it possible to embed a Google map without the point of interest selected? I couldn't find any answer for this in their API documentation.

```
<iframe style="width: 100%; min-height: 99%;" width="300" height="250" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?geocode=&amp;q=1005+Broadway+St.&amp;sll=40.0060577,-105.272949201246&amp;t=m&amp;gl=us&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;ll=40.0060577,-105.2729492&amp;spn=0.011505,0.018239&amp;z=15&amp;output=embed"></iframe>
```

Here's an example of what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/9XG5b/

I'd like for the white info box to not show up by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add an empty parameter `iwloc` to the url: http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/X6FMC/